# подключение к Mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Доброго времени суток, пытаюсь подключиться к онлайн бд mysql

```
string serverName = "mysql.zzz.com.ua";
        string userName = "root"; 
        string dbName = "dbname"; 
        string port = "3306"; 
        string password = "pass"; 
        string connStr = "server=" + serverName +
            ";user=" + userName +
            ";database=" + dbName +
            ";port=" + port +
            ";password=" + password + ";";
        var connectionString = "server=" + serverName + ";" + "database=" + dbName + ";" + "uid=" + userName + ";" + "pwd=" + password + ";";


        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Но при попытке соед `conn.Open();` вылазит исключение

```
> Возникло исключение "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException" в
> MySql.Data.dll ("Authentication to host 'mysql.zzz.com.ua' for user
> 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message:
> Logins are not allowed")  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
```

все данные верны. Можете подсказать в чем проблема ?

Comment: я не уверен, что на shared хостинге у вас логин `root`, если конечно вы не указали его в качестве примера здесь

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего на хостинге, куда вы пытаетесь подключится закрыт удаленный доступ к MySQL.

Открыть можно например вот так: http://kyunez.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/mysql-server.html

Если у вас shared хостинг, попросите хостера открыть доступ.